# listview error - code c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [listview error c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298874/listview-error-c)

I have a ListWiev. I want to select the first element from it and than invoke a method. The thing is that though i have the element in the listview I dont know why the following code is not working when i want to select the element. need help. thx

```
listview.Items[0].Selected = true;
listview.Select();
int c =listview.SelectedItems.Count;
MessageBox.Show(c + ": and : " + listview.Items[0].ToString()); .//here the c=0 and it should be 1:(
//  Thread.Sleep(3000);
method();
```

I have: ` ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem("a");

```
                it.SubItems.Add("s");
                it.SubItems.Add(""v");
                it.Tag = somethibg;
                listview.Items.Add(it);`
```

Comment: You've already asked this question once today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298874/listview-error-c

Comment: i know..but i didn'tpost the full code.

Comment: You can edit that previous question even after you've posted it.